# Uncaught ReferenceError: PythonShell is not defined - PythonShell for Nodejs and Electron

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, electron, es6-modules

I'm attempting to run a python script once a button is pressed with PythonShell in electron.

I have my imports in **main.js** and I call the opening of the python script through a separate js file. The file is in the form of a function and is called pybutton.js. The pybutton.js file is added through a `<script>` tag through HTML.

My main.js:

```
import {app, BrowserWindow} from 'electron'
import {PythonShell} from 'python-shell'
const path = require('path')

let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1100,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  //DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished initialization
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed. additional code for mac yuck.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow()
})
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Nexit</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/pybutton.js"></script> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Text!</p>
        <input type="button" class"submit" value="Python" onclick="pybutton()">
        <br>
        <img id="img" src="">
        <img id="imgp" src="">
    </body>
</html>
```

My pybutton.js:

```
function pybutton() {
    let options = {
        mode: 'text',
        pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
        scriptPath: '/../py'
    };

    PythonShell.run('pybutton.py', options, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
        console.log('results of pybutton: %j', results);
    });
}
```

When the button is clicked, I get this Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PythonShell is not defined
    at pybutton (pybutton.js:8)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html)
```

How would I define PythonShell a second time?

EDIT: Here is my renderer.js:

```
import {log} from 'console'

const path = require('path');

log('Hello from the renderer process!')

//-------------------------------------------------------------

import {PythonShell} from 'python-shell';
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');


const path = require('path');
```

I then added

to the `index.html`.

I continue to receive the same error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PythonShell is not defined
    at pybutton (pybutton.js:8)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:21)
```

so this still occurs on line 8 of my pybutton.js above. I must not be defining things correctly in the renderer.

Node modules used:

- Electron 4.1.2
- esm 3.2.25
- python-shell 2.0.3

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving this error ("PythonShell is not defined") because indeed, you did not define and import the PythonShell package in your renderer process.

You are loading PythonShell in your main process and then starting the BrowserWindow, which has no access to node packages by default. But as you already changed that by setting the `nodeIntegration` to `true`, you should now be able to easily import PythonShell in the renderer process instead of the main one.

Note that you may also need to provide the full (absolute) `scriptPath` in the options.

Comment: Thank you for a quick explanation and answer! I'll try this asap.

Comment: I added both: ```import {PythonShell} from 'python-shell';```
and: ``let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');``

to my renderer.js and added that js file to my html via 
```<script src="./renderer.js"></script>```

though still I'm finding the same issue.

Comment: Can you share what you currently have? And is it still the same error, or do you get a different message now? Anyways I'll try to get your example working later today, maybe you can find the issue before that on your own though.

Comment: I added an edit to the post if you're still interested